# Does the Comparable Class compare Strings based on length or ascii value? Java

Tags: java, text-extraction

I have a file of strings that looks like:

```
IX: {Series|(}              {2}
IX: {Series!geometric|(}    {5}
...
```

I wrote a binary search tree class and now I am trying to alphabetize the strings. The strings should be alphabetized because the overall task I am doing is making an index (an index at the end of a book). What I want to know is: does the comparable class compare strings based on ascii value or on string length? If it is based on length, how can I alphabetize these strings?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as in `Java` as `Comparable` *class*. Java does have `Comparable` *interface*. So what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: Did you know that the source code for these things is available for downloading/viewing for free? In fact, you probably have the code on your computer right now!

Comment: Strings compare *themselves* lexicographically, if that's what you're really asking. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Sorry everyone, I meant interface. And forgive me for trying to find a quicker answer rather than parsing the code of the interface.

Comment: But the quickest way would have been reading the Javadoc, instead of inventing a class and asking questions about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're  referring to `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()` the answer is - Neither. Strings are ordered by lexicographic/dictionary (alphabetically) order.

**Example:**

```
    String[] arr = {"bc", "bcc", "ab", "abc", "a", "bbc", "bb"};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // prints [a, ab, abc, bb, bbc, bc, bcc]
```

Comment: He could also be referring to ` TreeMap`, `PriorityQueue` or several other things, all irrelevant. The issue is what `String.compareTo()` does.

Comment: @EJP true - Strings natural order is alphabetic.